# Upgrading Tomcat From 8.0 to 8.5

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat8

We are upgrading our tomcat from 8.0 to 8.5 and we did some customization by using some of the Tomcat classes.

So there is one class `org.apache.catalina.util.LifeCycleSupport.java` which we are using, but in Tomcat 8.5 I am getting compilation error because this class is removed.

I did't find any documentation about this class removal.

Please suggest what is the alternative for this class?